# Seam cache provider with ehcache null

Tags: java, hibernate, seam, ehcache

I'm trying to configure seam/ehcache following the tutorial from jboss page:

http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.1.2/reference/en-US/html/cache.html

I put the ehcache.1.2.3.jar in project.ear/lib and injected CacheProvider as especified, but the CacheProvider always return null. The documentation doesn't show any aditional configuration for ehcache, just for jboss cache.

I am probably doing something wrong, it's impossible be so easy :).

besides put the jar in /lib, i created the following seam component to test:

```
@Scope(ScopeType.SESSION)
@Name("cacheBean")
public class CacheSeamBean implements java.io.Serializable {

 @In(required=false, create=true) 
 private EntityManager em;

 @Logger 
 private Log log;

 @In
 private Events events;

 @In CacheProvider cacheProvider;

 Boolean blLoaded = Boolean.FALSE;

 @Create
 public void buscar() {

  if (!blLoaded){
   List<Parametro> lstParametro = em.createQuery("select p from Parametro p").getResultList();
   for (Parametro parametro : lstParametro){
    cacheProvider.put(parametro.getCodigo(), parametro.getValor());
   }
   blLoaded= Boolean.TRUE;
  }
 }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add into your components.xml:

```
<components xmlns="http://jboss.com/products/seam/components"
...
            xmlns:cache="http://jboss.com/products/seam/cache"
            xsi:schemaLocation=
                    "http://jboss.com/products/seam/core http://jboss.com/products/seam/core-2.1.xsd
               http://jboss.com/products/seam/cache http://www.jboss.com/products/seam/cache-2.1.xsd">

...
   <cache:eh-cache-provider/>
...
</components>
```

Comment: I added the above snippet in the components.xml and it still didn't work for me.

Comment: @Joshua do you have the ehcache jar in the classpath? (project.ear/lib) that's all you should need to get it working. 

If you have a non-default ehcache.xml, that needs to be in the root of your application classpath too, (eg WEB-INF/classes)